# Ember access another controller inside of IndexController?

Tags: ember.js

How do I access another controller inside the Index Controller in Ember?

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    doSomethingToAnotherController: function(params) { 
            // how do I access another controller other than the index controller here?
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `needs` to connect one controller to another:

```
App.OtherController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    //... code here
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['other'],
    doSomethingToAnotherController: function() {
      //you can access the 'other' controller via get for example:
      this.get('controllers.other').doSomething();
    }
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e2fXn/

However, there seems to be [an open issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2376) that this will break when used inside an `{{#each}}` loop (this might be relevant since your `IndexController` extends `ArrayController`).

Hope this helps!